# How to create a folder out of the first few letters of a filename?

Tags: c#, file, directory

So I checked out the basic things but I'd like to do the following:

I have 5 files let's say: X1_word_date.pdf, XX1_word_date.pdf, etc...

I'd like to create a folder structure like: C:\PATH\X1, C:\PATH\XX1, etc...

So how do I take the first letters before the '_' in the file names and put it into a string?

My idea is that I use the Directory.CreateDirectory and than combine the main path and the strings so I get the folders.

How do I do that? Help appreciated.

Comment: You want to move the files into these folders?

Comment: Hi you are on a good path to your solution. What you need is to learn basic string  manipulations. Check this tutorial (especially Split and IndexOf methods):[String manipulation](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/329281-string-manipulation/)

Comment: What if it's a double digit? Like X23?

Comment: Is the First part before the first `_` in the file name the exact match for the path? or just the number?

Comment: If you want anything before the _  you can do a string split into a variable, and use directory create, like you said, have the begining part of the directory stored in one variable, and you add the new direcotry after it.  But do a check if directory exists before trying to create it

Comment: @TimSchmelter yes. moving them and then also creating them if they don't exist already. When creating them I want to use the first letters of the filenames to name them. So: Move "XY_something_date.pdf" to the folder "C:/Dir/XY" and so on...

Comment: @Reniuz Thanks I'll check it out.

Comment: `str.Substring(0,str.IndexOf('_')-1)`

Comment: @xdtTransform Yes they consist out of few letters and few numbers. like XZXZ1234

Comment: @Brad I'll try and tell you how it worked out! Thanks

Comment: Is it just me that notices the title does not match the question? Your title says you want to create a folder with the first 4 letters of a file name, yet your ideal solution contains folders with only the first 2 letters.

Comment: @ColinM Yes just realized it... actually I'm looking for a solution where the names can change. Generally 8 letters but it can go up to 12... gonna edit it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string fileName = "X1_word_date.pdf";
string[] tokens = fileName.Split('_');
string myPath = "C:\\PATH\\";
Directory.CreateDirectory( myPath + tokens[0]);
```

Something like this should work. Using `Split()` will also allow for numbers greater than 9 to be dealt with

Comment: Suggestion to use Path.Combine instead of concatenation.

Comment: It wokred! Thank you, but what if I don't know the letters beforehand? I've already tried to replace "X1_word_date.pdf" with *_word_*.pdf but it said: Illegal character...

Answer (score 3):

Supposed that your `files` is a `List<string>` which contains the file name (X2_word_date.pdf,...)

```
files.ForEach(f => {
    var pathName=  f.Split('_').FirstOrDefault();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(pathName))
    {
        var directoryInfo = DirectoryInfo(Path.Combine(@"C:\PATH", pathName));
        if(!directoryInfo.Exists)
            directoryInfo.Create();

       //Then move this current file to the directory created, by FileInfo and Move method 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

With simple string methods like `Split` and the `System.IO.Path` class:

```
var filesAndFolders = files
.Select(fn => new
{
    File = fn,
    Dir = Path.Combine(@"C:\PATH", Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fn).Split('_')[0].Trim())
});
```

If you want to create that folder and add the file:

```
foreach (var x in filesAndFolders)
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(x.Dir); // will only create it if it doesn't exist yet
    string newFileName = Path.Combine(x.Dir, x.File);
    // we don't know the old path of the file so i can't show how to move
}
```

Comment: becareful of null at [0]

Comment: @ThierryV: `String.Split` never returns null

Comment: @ThierryV in what conditions you can get null at [0]?

Comment: ah, I saw, it never be null :). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Or using regex

```
            string mainPath = @"C:\PATH";
            string[] filenames = new string[] { "X1_word_date.pdf", "X2_word_date.pdf" };
            foreach (string filename in filenames)
            {
                Match foldernameMatch = Regex.Match(filename, "^[^_]+");
                if (foldernameMatch.Success)
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(mainPath, foldernameMatch.Value));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the bigger picture starting with only your Source and Destination directory.
We can list all files we need to move with [Directory.GetFiles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2(v=vs.110).aspx).
In this list We first isolate the filename with [GetFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx).
Using simple [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) you have the new directory name.
[Directory.CreateDirectory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) will create directories unless they already exist.
To move the file we need its destination path, a combinaison of the Destination directory path and the fileName.

```
string sourceDirectory = @"";
string destDirectory = @"";

string[] filesToMove = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDirectory); 

foreach (var filePath in filesToMove) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    var dirPath = Path.Combine(destDirectory, fileName.Split('_')[0]);
    var fileNewPath= Path.Combine(dirPath,fileName);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath);// If it exist it does nothing.
    File.Move(filePath, fileNewPath);
}
```